# .NET 4.0: What is the true purpose of dynamics?

Tags: dynamic, .net-4.0

I haven't used 4.0 in depth, but have played with dynamics in a sample app to see them in action.  At first, it would appear that dynamics are a sort of way for developers to "hack" code so that they can implement the architecture of generics and/or inheritance in an application that wasn't written with such architecture in mind.

Other than bringing back the old VB6-style object, what advantages are gained by introducing dynamic types into your app?  In other words, how can dynamics be used "wisely"?

Comment: a trivial internet search would turn up an answer to this

Comment: I checked out a few articles, but they didn't really show dynamics being used in a practical fashion.  I thought I'd come here to trim the fat and get an exact answer to my question sans a huge article write-up and give stackoverflow the Google credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best use of `dynamic` in .NET is when interacting with APIs from dynamic typing languages such as JavaScript and Python. You need the dynamic keyword to more easily interact in such architectures and I would suspect that any other use of dynamic is not wise, i.e. a code smell.

From the [dynamic reference:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

> The dynamic type simplifies access to COM APIs such as the Office
>   Automation APIs, and also to dynamic APIs such as IronPython
>   libraries, and to the HTML Document Object Model (DOM).